# Как обратиться к элементу в javascript?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли в js обращаться к элементу по такой конструкции: `document.getElementById(id1 or id2 or id3)` то есть при обращении указывать что нужно взять один из этих элементов если он есть.
Подскажите если да то какой синтаксис будет правильным или есть ли альтернатива такому запросу?

Comment: можно использовать querySelectorAll и `,`

Comment: Вот [подобный вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408891/getelementbyid-multiple-ids), ответ думаю вам подойдёт.

Comment: @РоманКруглов Все верно, это то что искал, благодарю вас.